# HTTPS request via Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, glassfish

I have a little problem with the development of an https request with in an ManagedBean. The problem is that I'm getting following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'bitpay.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=bitpay.com, O="BitPay, Inc.", L=Atlanta, ST=Georgia, C=US, SERIALNUMBER=5163966, OID.2.5.4.15=Private Organization, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US)
```

But if I try the code in a pure java client it works perfectly fine.
Does anyone know where my failure is?

I've used the code from this [repository](https://github.com/bitpay/java-client).

My own code is following:

```
import model.BitPay;
import model.Invoice;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;


@Named(value = "bitPayMBean")
@Dependent
public class BitPayMBean {

    private static final String API_KEY = "";

    @Named(value = "returnUrl")
    private String returnUrl = "URL";

    public void setReturnUrl(String returnUrl) {
        this.returnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public String getReturnUrl() {
        return returnUrl;
    }

    public BitPayMBean() {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

    }

    public void transaction(double value) {
        BitPay bitpay = new BitPay(API_KEY, "USD");
        Invoice invoice = bitpay.createInvoice(value);
        setReturnUrl(invoice.getUrl());
    }

}
```

Cheers and thanks for your advise

Comment: Invalid keystore. GlassFish uses his own keystores located at $GFHOME/domains/yourdomain/config. Take a look at SSL section, Network config->Protocols in the GF Admin.

Comment: At first thanks for your answer @vzamanillo Your point was this line of code `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");` right? This file is linking to my certificate file in $GFHOME/domains/yourdomain/config. I took also a look at the admin console and there is the certificate "s1as" configured. And this certificate is a valid certificate in this keystore. Any additional ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've solved my problem. The problem was that in my cert file of JDK version 8 hasn't all cetificates intetegrated which where in my cert file of the JDK version 6. So i've integrated the missing certs of the jdk6 in my jdk8 cert file. That solved my problem